# Swap column values in MySql

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am trying to swap some column value, and can't really figure out how its done. Lets say I have 2 rows, one with an ID of 2 and another with an ID of 5. Both of these rows have a column called "position".

I want to swap "position" from the row with ID of 2, to the "position" of the row with an ID of 5.

So if the ID-2 row's position is 34 and the ID-5 row's position is 12

```
ID position
2    34
5    12
```

the new values would then be:

```
ID position
2    12
5    34
```

How would this be done?

Comment: What you wrote is usually called a *statement*. You stated something. On this website, people **ask** and other people **answer**. To establish this communication, the one who **asks** provides the question with *details* about the problem, attempted solution and where they got stuck. People providing the *answer* fill in the blanks. Do you see where you went wrong?

Comment: @N.B. Just made it a question, thanks for the heads up :)
There is no attempted solutions, as I have no clue whatsoever, on how this could be accomplished.

Comment: So you're stuck on syntax, general how-to or what? You know how to do an `UPDATE` query or?

Comment: Generally, swapping a and b is done by setting a to x, b to a, and x to b. You might bind this logic up in a transaction.

Comment: @N.B. Yes I am familiar with UPDATE, but I dont know how to use it correctly in this manner. I tried something like "UPDATE 'table' set position=x WHERE id=2," and then got stuck...

Comment: Did  you get any errors back? Also, did you really quote the table name using single quote character?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this in one go, you can use a simple `UPDATE` statement.
Note: if you plan to copy the code here, copy it fully and don't quote your table or column names using single quote character (this one: `'`).

```
UPDATE `your_table` a 
INNER JOIN `your_table` b 
ON a.id = 2 AND b.id = 5

SET a.`position` = b.`position`, b.`position` = a.`position`
```

Example:

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gocGTSaSM3QXfmrcvC28JP/1